# how summernote editor storing the in mongodb with meteor

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, summernote

I am able to store in the mongodb in html format like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "GwgCygRMgsB8jRBFr",
    "html" : "<p>mid</p><ol><li><b>m</b></li><li>,mbgb</li><li>lgkbg</li><li>b,g</li></ol><p><br></p><p><br></p>"
}
{
    "_id" : "XyK5jaLgQNxJyDP4u",
    "html" : "<p>mid</p><ol><li><b>m</b></li><li>,mbgb</li><li>lgkbg</li><li>b,g</li></ol><p><br></p><p><br></p>"
}
```

I want to store only a text edit in the textarea not the  elements of he html how i need to send only the text can anybody help ,I am trying this since form two two days I am new to meteor .

Answer (score 0):

Before storing it in the database you can filter the text using regular expressions. But they aren't accurate 100% of time.

```
var htmlString = "<div><p>Paragraph 1 text</p><p>Paragraph 2 text</div>";

var regEx = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;

htmlString.replace(regEx, " "); //this will replace you html tags with space
```

output would be "Paragraph 1 text Paragraph 2 text"

You can test you regular expression like below

```
var isValid = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig.test("<p>Some text</p>");
```